# Identify if processor config is higher that i3 with system_info2

Tags: flutter, dart

How could I identify if the CPU configuration is higher than i3 on flutter?

I have already used `system_info2` to retrieve the information but for the comparison it is a bit difficult for me.

Here is my code:

```
bool isCPUHigherThanI3() {
    final cores = SysInfo.cores;
    bool isCPUCoreI = cores.first.name.contains('i');
    if (isCPUCoreI) {
      var coreNameList = cores.first.name.split(' ');
      var coreI = coreNameList.elementAt(2);
      if (int.parse(coreI.split('').elementAt(1)) >= 3) {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      if (Platform.isMacOS) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```